# How to convert alphabets to numerical values with spaces and return it back to alphabets?

Tags: matlab, encoding

Want to convert the alphabet to numerical values and transform it back to alphabets using some mathematical techniques like fast Fourier transform in MATLAB.

Example:
The following is the text saved in "text2figure.txt" file

```
Hi how r u am fine take care of your health 
thank u very much
am 2.0
```

Reading it in MATLAB:

```
data=fopen('text2figure.txt','r')
d=fscanf(data,'%s')
temp = fileread( 'text2figure.txt' ) 
temp = regexprep( temp, ' {6}', '   NaN' ) 
c=cellstr(temp(:))'
```

Now I wish to convert cell array with spaces to numerical values/integers:

```
coding = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz .,;'
str = temp %// example text
[~, result] = ismember(str, coding)
y=result


result =

  Columns 1 through 18

     0     9    28     8    16    24    28    19    28    22    28     1    13    28     6     9    14     5

  Columns 19 through 36

    28    21     1    11     5    28     3     1    19     5    28    16     6    28    26    16    22    19

  Columns 37 through 54

    28     8     5     1    12    21     8    28     0     0    21     8     1    14    11    28    22    28

  Columns 55 through 71

    23     5    19    26    28    13    22     3     8     0     0     1    13    28     0    29     0
```

---

Now I wish to convert the numerical values back to alphabets:

```
Hi how r u am fine take care of your health 
thank u very much
am 2.0
```

How to write a MATLAB code to return the numerical values in the variable `result` to alphabets?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] showing your inputs, your desired outputs, how you are attempting to achieve those outputs and how your attempts are failing to meet your requirements. We can't help you without more information.

Comment: I've voted to reopen your question, but I think we still need your desired output. From your sample text, do you only want the value `2.0`, or something more?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the code in the question doesn't have any useful effects. These three lines are the ones that lead to `result`:

```matlab
str = fileread('test2figure.txt');
coding = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz .,;';
[~, result] = ismember(str, coding);
```

`ismember` returns, in the second output argument, the indices into `coding` for each element of `str`. Thus, `result` are indices that we can use to index into `coding`:

```matlab
out = coding(result);
```

However, this does not work because some elements of `str` do not occur in `coding`, and for those elements `ismember` returns 0, which is not a valid index. We can replace the zeros with a new character:

```matlab
coding = ['*',coding];
out = coding(result+1);
```

Basically, we're shifting each code by one, adding a new code for 1.

One of the characters we're missing here is the newline character. Thus the three lines have become one line. You can add a code for the newline character by adding it to the `coding` table:

```matlab
str = fileread('test2figure.txt');
coding = ['abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz .,;',char(10)]; % char(10) is the newline character
[~, result] = ismember(str, coding);

coding = ['*',coding];
out = coding(result+1);
```

---

All of this is easier to achieve just using the ASCII code table:

```matlab
str = fileread('test2figure.txt');
result = double(str);

out = char(result);
```